# Assign to associative array element indirectly

Tags: bash, shell-script

When I have the following:

```
a=foo
b=baz
```

I can use

```
typeset "$a=$b"
```

But this fails if a references an array element:

```
$ a=foo[bar]
$ b=baz
$ typeset "$a=$b"
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="baz")
```

i.e. for some reason bar is treated like a variable name. Any ideas how to change this so I can have as result `declare -A foo=([bar]="baz")`, preferably without parsing `$a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never declared `foo` as an associative array. Arrays and "scalars" (for want of a  better word describing ordinary variables) never have to be declared, but associative arrays do.

Since you did not declare `foo` as an associative array, your code sets `foo[0]` to `baz`.  It sets index zero because `bar` is being used in an arithmetic context (since it's an ordinary array assignment). Your `bar` variable, used as an index in an ordinary array, either has the value zero, or it is unset (does not exist).

In short, there is nothing in the statement `foo[bar]=baz` that says `foo` is an associative array.  By default, it would be an ordinary array and `bar` would be interpreted in an arithmetic context as some integer index (its value would be evaluated to zero if that variable did not exist).

To get what you want, you will need to declare `foo` as an associative array.

```bsh
a=foo[bar]
b=baz

declare -A foo

typeset "$a=$b"
declare -p foo
```

This would output

```
declare -A foo=([bar]="baz" )
```

Comment: Yes, but the underlying problem is that there's a whole set of (a,b) pairs coming from a file and I meant to treat associative arrays the same as other variables that were set this way previously.

Comment: @TJahns If you could describe the overall issue in your question, I could possibly say something bout that. At the moment though, all I have is "I have this ..., and it does not work, why and what to do?".  Associative arrays _need_ to be declare before assigned to.

Comment: @TJahns Note also that syntactically, there is nothing in `foo[bar]=baz` that says `foo` is an associative array and not an ordinary array.

Comment: I wrote in the original question that I'd like to not parse `$a`, if I need to emit `declare -A ${a%[*}` conditionally then obviously that requires parsing. I could have been more explicit in that `$a` and `$b` are examples but I imagined them being variables somehow clarifies the issue.

Comment: @TJahns   what you want to do is more easily done with something like:  `declare -A foo; while read -r key value ; do foo["$key"]="$value"; done < file.txt; declare -p foo`.    You may also need to set the IFS shell variable to match the input file's format (e.g. if your input is delimited by anything other than whitespace)

Comment: note that you need to redirect your data into the while-read loop - you can't use a pipe because (in short, simplified) pipes are run in a sub-shell so the while loop will be **unable** to modify the parent shell's variables.   You **can** use redirection and [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (e.g. if you need to pre-process the data with awk or sed or grep or something).

Comment: I conclude that this question has no answer to the effect I'd like, and hence I've added a parse step to the effect that any lhs in the input of the form `word[otherword]` leads to a `declare -A word` before the assignment.